# Uninstalling Ubuntu dual-boot bootrec issues

Tags: upgrade, dual-boot, windows, uninstall, boot-repair

So on my laptop I am currently planning on uninstalling Ubuntu 12.04 so I can upgrade my Windows 7 partition to Windows 8, then install Ubuntu 12.10. My issue being that when I boot the Windows 7 recovery disk, I believe i Need to use `cmd` to run `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /fixmbr`. Now, whilst `fixmbr` works, `fixboot` yields me with an error regarding an unrecognised volume.

When I turn on my PC now, I am no longer met the GRUB option, so I boot straight into Windows. My question is:

As such, do I still need to have `fixboot` run or can I just format and resize the partitions now even with the error when running `fixboot`?

Answer (score 0):

> As such, do I still need to have fixboot run or can I just format and
>   resize the partitions now even with the error when running fixboot?

If I were you:

Follow this tutorial to restore completely the MBR:

[MBR - Restore Windows 7 Master Boot Record](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)

Then boot in to Windows and delete the Ubuntu partitions if you want. Allocate the space again to Windows and proceed with any plans you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
do I still need to have fixboot run or can I just format and resize the partitions
now even with the error when running fixboot?
```

You can boot successfully into Windows, so everything is fine, you don't need to use `fixboot`.